# customize grails exception message

Tags: grails

when I specify empty on a date field (which has time part filled in, so not null), the following message is displayed in the UI

```
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type org.joda.time.DateTime for property responseRequiredDate; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "structT00:00:00"
```

is there a way to customize this message. Or do one need custom exception handling as described here [link text](http://blog.bruary.net/2008/03/grails-custom-exception-handling.html)

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That is an exception.  AFAIK you can't customize it other than by catching it and outputting what you want.